# jquery ajax autocomplete search, How can i make tag autocomplete search with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, search, autocomplete

Suppose there are tags in the database table, or in a text file or in a xml file.

Now when an user type something in the textbox, it will call the jquery ajax autocomplete searching function like we do for stackoverflow tags adding.

How can i do this with jquery ajax? Can someone post complete code with example?

I have read this, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete,  but could not understand how to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you using the [jQuery UI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote). The documentation provides a full example of how to set it up with AJAX.

You put an input field:

```
<input id="tags" name="tags" />
```

and then apply the plugin:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: '/tags',
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

This will invoke the `/tags` server side script and pass it the term query string parameter that will contain the input value. For example: `/tags?term=asp`. The server will then use the `asp` value to look in the database and respond with a JSON of the following form:

```
[ { "id": "1", "label": "label 1", "value": "value 1" }, 
  { "id": "2", "label": "label 2", "value": "value 2" },
  { "id": "3", "label": "label 3", "value": "value 3" },
  ...
]
```

which will represent an array of objects that match the search criteria and which will be shown in the dropdown.

Obviously the implementation of the server side script will greatly depend on the server side language you are using, the database access technology, ...

Comment: Where is the search.php? What will be the contents of search.php? How will it return data?

Comment: @guru, that's an entirely different question regarding PHP. I would recommend you asking it separately as it no longer has anything to do with the Autocomplete plugin that you were asking here. But before asking it make sure you do some efforts on your side or the question might be closed. For example, check one of the gazillions of articles on the web and try to implement it: http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/